# Simple hello world app - Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

I just found out about Cucumber, and it seems to be more inclined towards behavior driven testing? Or not?

Also, I got this sample code:

```
public class HelloStepdefs {
    private Hello hello;
    private String hi;

    @Given("^I have a hello app with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_have_a_hello_app_with(String greeting) {
        hello = new Hello(greeting);
    }

    @When("^I ask it to say hi$")
    public void I_ask_it_to_say_hi() {
        hi = hello.sayHi();
    }

    @Then("^it should answer with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void it_should_answer_with(String expectedHi) {
        assertEquals(expectedHi, hi);
    }
}
```

From my understanding this class will initiate Hello class because of the `@Given` annotation, then if the method that is annotated with `@When` is executed, it will call the method with `@Then` annotation?

Anyway Cucumber seems to be very interesting, however, how does it work with existing design patterns as well as with existing frameworks like Spring etc.

Furthermore, how can this be used when dealing with database oriented designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cucumber](http://cukes.info/) is indeed a BDD tool, and it originated from the ruby community.  [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) is the java implementation.

Regarding [Given/When/Then](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Given-When-Then), these are aliases for individual steps in features files, and ruby doesn't distinguish between them.  But they are valuable because they give context to the various stakeholders that are authoring, implementing, or reading the features.

In terms of integration with spring, [cuke4duke](https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/wiki/Spring) might fit the bill.